# Iam trying to migrate ADAL.net to MSAL.net using .net framework 4.8.I need to replace the following lines of code which are in adal.net to msal.net

Tags: asp.net

```
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}"

ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(sharedSecretAppId, sharedSecretKey);

AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientCred).ConfigureAwait(false);

return result.AccessToken;
```